# Illegal Key Size - AES CBC Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I am doing some simple encryption/decryption coding, and I am having a problem, which I cannot figure out by myself.

I have a ciphertext which is hex encoded. The ciphertext is AES with a block length of 128bits and a key length of 256bits. The cipher block mode is CBC. IV is the first block of the cipher text.

The Exception Message is Illegal Key Size.

Here is my decrypt() function:

```
public static byte[] decrypt() throws Exception
{
    try{
        byte[] ciphertextBytes = convertToBytes("cb12f5ca1bae224ad44fdff6e66f9a53e25f1000183ba5568958430c11c6eafc62c04de8bf27e0ac7104b598fb492142");
        byte[] keyBytes = convertToBytes("CFDC65CB003DD50FF5D6D826D62CF9CA6C64489D60CB02D18C1B58C636F8220D");
        byte[] ivBytes = convertToBytes("cb12f5ca1bae224a");

        SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes);
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
     return null;
}
```

And I have those functions to do the conversion String/ByteArray

```
    //convert ByteArray to Hex String
public static String convertToHex(byte[] byteArray)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : byteArray)
    {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

//convert String to ByteArray
private static byte[] convertToBytes(String input) {
    int length = input.length();
    byte[] output = new byte[length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        output[i / 2] = (byte) ((digit(input.charAt(i), 16) << 4) | digit(input.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Maybe you can help me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't that message about the key size policy used by Oracle JRE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have hit the [key-size limit in Oracle JRE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#importlimits). From the linked document:

> If stronger algorithms are needed (for example, AES with 256-bit keys), the [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) must be obtained and installed in the JDK/JRE.
>
> It is the user's responsibility to verify that this action is permissible under local regulations.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I downloaded the file and copied it to the security folder of my JRE installation!

SOLVED

Comment: I found it easier to just uncomment "crypto.policy=unlimited" from the java.security file of my JRE (as of 8u161, no need to download new policy files). This is explained in Appendix C: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppC